# WORDPRESS: storing meta (check) box values with register_setting (possible?) and posting a form to content section of pages

Tags: php, html, wordpress

this is my first time making a wordpress plugin and I am a novice developer.

I need to create a checkbox that gives the admin the option of including a form ***within*** the content section of a page. The admin will be given the option of either enabling or disabling this form **for each page** based on whether the box is ticked or not. I have a couple of problems:

1. not sure if I can save metabox values to admin settings? if not can I create a settings field in the form of a metabox to store the setting? I want the option to appear at the bottom of the page editor
2. How can I then post the form to the content section of the page? I need an if statement to check if the box is ticked; is there a way I can then ''do_shortcode()'' to echo out the form into the editor and thus the content section of the page, not touching any other part of the page?

I'm just looking for ideas at this stage.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need one checkbox that adds a form to every page, make it a system setting - this is different than a metabox - it is something you will retrieve with `get_option()`, and save with `update_option()`

If you need a checkbox on every page's edit form to decide whether or not that particular page outputs the form when viewed, then you want to add it as a metabox to the page.  This is something you'll get with `get_post_meta()`

The main difference is a settings value is post-independant.  It has one value for everything.  A meta value is post-dependant.  It is stored in the postmeta table by the post's ID and, as such, each post can have a different value (or even multiple values - so be careful when coding this - you'll probably want to exclusively use `update_post_meta()`, rather than `add_post_meta()`)

As for how to post the form to the page you'll either want to edit your theme's single-page.php file, check for the admin or meta value, and output the form.  Or you could look into the filter 'single_template' to load a completely different template depending on the setting / meta value

So, in short:
1) No you cannot save a metabox value to an admin setting.  You want a metabox for that particular content type using the `add_meta_box()` function
2) You will most likely need to edit your theme (preferably by creating a child-theme)